# Where can I find a opengl pixel shader example for smooth SpotLight?

Tags: special-effects

I am using Ardor3D, and find the spotlight is quite bumpy. Anybody has a good pixel shader can smooth the edges of the spot light?

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is something similar to soft shadows, only lightening instead. You could have a look at both nVidia and ATI's developer sections for sample shaders to do all sorts of things.